# Dataset of Home Appliance Usage

Tags: data-request, energy

I'm interested in obtaining a dataset that includes the electricity usage of individual home appliances measured at hourly intervals. An example of such a dataset is the [IRISE Project](http://remodece.isr.uc.pt/database/Campaign_Irise.htm) from [REMODECE](http://remodece.isr.uc.pt/). Unfortunately the data provided on their website contains daily averages and I need the data for each day. Does anyone have any idea of datasets that contain this information, or how to obtain the full IRISE dataset?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "individual home appliances". A hair dryer listed at 1.8 kW will consume exactly that. Do you mean "hourly household consumption data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [The Almanac of Minutely Power dataset Version 2](http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201637) captures three major types of energy consumption, namely electricity, water, and gas. It includes data from many individual home appliances such as clothes dryer, clothes washer, dishwasher, heat pump, fridge, TV, wall oven, etc.
   The data were captured in a Canadian residential house over a 2-year period (1 minute intervals). Also, it has been beautifully cleaned and ready to be analyzed.
2. [DRED (Dutch Residential Energy Dataset)](http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~akshay/dred/) contains energy consumption data of a residential house in the Netherlands over 6 months (1 minute intervals). It also has data of individual appliance.

Comment: Unfortunately the link for the DRED dataset is not active anymore, so I can't download the dataset. Does anybody know an alternative download link or has downloaded the data in the past and can hand them over to me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to look at the REFIT project for such datasets:

[REFIT: Electrical Load Measurements (Cleaned)](https://pure.strath.ac.uk/portal/en/datasets/refit-electrical-load-measurements-cleaned(9ab14b0e-19ac-4279-938f-27f643078cec).html)

> The REFIT Electrical Load Measurements dataset includes cleaned electrical consumption data in Watts for 20 households at aggregate and appliance level, timestamped and sampled at 8 second intervals.